# Set defaults for a dropdown generated using a ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

```
<ul ng-repeat="books in companyBookData.Bookparts" style="float: left">
    <li>
        <select 
            name="Zone" 
            id="Zone" 
            ng-options=" ZoneType.Description for ZoneType in books.ZoneTypes" 
            ng-model="ZoneType" 
            ng-init="ZoneType=books.ZoneTypes[0]">
        </select>
    </li>
<ul>
```

I have dropdowns which are generated using ng-repeat as shown above. I will have a minimum of 4 dropdowns and maximum of 100 and I understand that ng-repeat creates a new scope on every iteration. How do I set the defaults for each of the dropdowns? Will I have access to all the scopes generated by ng-repeat? How do I set the defaults?

Comment: Try like ul ng-repeat="books in companyBookData.Bookparts" ng-controller="MyCtrl" in MyCtrl you have a reference to each books

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul ng-repeat="books in companyBookData.Bookparts" style="float: left">
<li>
    <select 
        name="Zone" 
        id="Zone" 
        ng-options=" ZoneType.Description for ZoneType in books.ZoneTypes" 
        ng-model="ZoneType" 
        ng-init="ZoneType=books.ZoneTypes[0]"
        ng-controller="ZoneTypeController"
        >
    </select>
</li>
```

As suggested by Whisher I added a ng-controller directive and set the default there. This controller is invoked for every iteration of companyBookData.Bookparts.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
ng-init="ZoneType= ZoneType || books.ZoneTypes[0]">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign the same property for ng-model and ng-options. You can use ng-init as you were using just define a new variable to store the selected object.

```
<ul ng-repeat="books in companyBookData.Bookparts" style="float: left">
    <li ng-init="selectedZoneType=books.ZoneTypes[0]">
        <select 
            name="Zone"
            ng-options=" ZoneType.Description for ZoneType in books.ZoneTypes" 
            ng-model="selectedZoneType">
        </select>
    </li>
<ul>
```

Don't define ids inside ng-repeat or you will get duplicates id in the html. Unless you use $index to make them unique.